# Is this fan set up risky, will harm the MoBo?

Tags: cooling

I want to have an extra fan but the mobo lacks a socket. Only cable that comes out of power unit and seems free is this 4 hole one. Is it wise to solder this two pin fan cable to this (Port A) cable's ends?

What's the order to do it?  (red to red black to black or red to black)

(I dont have any adepters. No local shops have them and some sale girls even laughed at asking for that thing to that fan thing adepter)

The cable and socket that comes out of the Power Unit

[image: https://i.imgsafe.org/064bab592a.jpg]

The culprit

[image: https://i.imgsafe.org/06d9c25e06.jpg]

Comment: I'd like to add, your imagehost didn't play well with the upload dialog in SU. Might want to use imgur next time, even if you can't inline images.

Answer (score 2):

The correct name for your first image is called a molex or IDE 4 pin. The second is just a 2 pin fan.

You want a connector that looks like [This](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Delock-Cable-power-Molex-4-pin-male-4-x-2-pin-fan-power-up-to-4-fans-30-cm-/161889107000?hash=item25b157bc38:g:Dr0AAOSwQjZXPuNo).
Grab one off ebay or a similar local site to you rather than bodging, it will do you well in the long run.

A single version of the cable looks like [This](http://www.moddiy.com/products/4%252dPin-Molex-Connector-(Male)-to-2%252dPin-GPU-Mini-Fan-Connector-(Male-2.5mm).html?setCurrencyId=6&gclid=CL3qmPnFos4CFUa6GwodVrMAww)

Black & Red are power. The  third pin on fans you can get (Not yours in this instance.) is for your motherboard to read the speed of the fan.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't harm the motherboard, but its not a good idea to do it without understanding what you're doing, or even whether the fan is needed.

Black is always at ground. Red is at 5V. The PSU's usually designed to be somewhat sacrificial and the worst that could happen with some boards is you get a short, and the system shuts down.

Soldering though means if you mess up its going to be harder to fix. Cable *splicing* is hard, and you need to make sure the individual cables are solidly mechanically fixed and insulated.

You're also going to need to make sure the connectors on the molex that arn't in use are properly insulated and this will be pretty much an irreversible change.

In short... Its probably not worth it. If you must, make sure you do it right